# RequestFocus on Edittext shows up after being removed/deleted from xml code

Tags: android

I had defined a `<requestfocus />` tag in xml for my edittext widget for my android 2.2 app. Later on, I removed the `<requestfocus />` tag, but the activity in which the edittext is defined is still showing up the soft android keyboard.
I have re-designed the code similar to another activity where the `<requestfocus />` never shows up, but this edittext activity still throws up the soft android keyboard.

Any suggestions on how to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in your activity

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```